# Windows 10 UWA (Image display)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10-universal

I am displaying images in a list view. When I click then I need to open that image full screen in the same application. So when the user clicks the back button it should take it back to the list view. Which control or how can I do that(displaying image full screen). Fairly new to c# and UWA development.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> When I click then I need to open that image full screen in the same application

For your requirements, one simple way is that you can navigate to a second page from the ListView and show the image full screen the page with a [ImageControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx).
Navigation code like follows:

```
 private void Image_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Image selectedimage = e.OriginalSource as Image;
     Images select = (Images)selectedimage.DataContext;
     Frame.Navigate(typeof(ShowImage),select);
 }
```

Another way is to use a [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) control to show the image with fly-out visual effects. If you want to show the image full-screen you need to set the [FullSizeDesired](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.fullsizedesired.aspx) property of ContentDialog to true. ContentDialog code as follows:

```
<ContentDialog
 ...
   FullSizeDesired ="True" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
   Canvas.ZIndex="1" MaxHeight="1920" MaxWidth="1440">
   <Image x:Name="showimage" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"  Stretch="Fill" Margin="0"></Image>
</ContentDialog>
```

> So when the user clicks the back button it should take it back to the list view.

For this, you need to enable the system [back button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt465734.aspx) navigation and configure it to let the second page can back to the main page. Code for back button in `App.xaml.cs` as follows:

```
private void App_BackRequested(object sender,
    Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame == null)
        return; 
    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

I tested it, both of the two methods I provided above can back to the ListView by back button. More details please reference the completed demo [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/tree/master/CListViewNavigate), you can download for testing to see if it is what you want.

Additionally, following the [universal application platform guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) to explore more about uwp development.